# Get venue details without auth (Foursquare)

Tags: java, android, foursquare

According to Foursquare's dev site, venue details do not require user auth:

HTTP Method GET
Requires Acting User    No (learn more)
Modes supported foursquare, swarm (learn more)

But the example uses a oauth token and if you try searching with your client credentials, you get a 400 response.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&v=20140714
```

returns:

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}
```

Does anybody know of a way to get venue details without having user logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sigh**

The issue was with my code.  I was putting my client ID in twice.

just so everybody knows, the above works :)